# Register all autofac modules from assembly by one line

Tags: .net, ioc-container, autofac

I can register all `Autofac` modules (classes derived from Autofac.Module) one by one using line like this

`builder.RegisterModule(new LoggingInjectionModule());`

But if I have 10 or more modules I want just to specify assembly, where `Autofac` can find all modules, that it need to register. Is there is any way to register all modules from specific assembly, namespace by single line or two lines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the different overloads (see [API doc](http://autofac.org/apidoc/?topic=html/F680C6AB.htm)) of the `RegisterAssemblyModules` method:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```